# Report in PDF format not showing text like X & Y axis label and text in legends

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperRepotrs 3.7.5* for generation of reports in my project.

Every thing went fine but when I executed my project in Linux environment, report generated in *PDF* format as I designed but the legends and graph in my report not showing text like X & Y axis label and text in legends.

Any help on this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

select the chart then go to Properties

Under the `BarPlot Properties`  tick `Show Tick Labels`